# Need to show the div for 2 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2sections in my code. I need to show the sections one by one for 2seconds.Please help me on this.

```
<section class="square_box tctgrid" id="question1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
<section class="square_box tctgrid" id="question1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div  class="empty"></div>
</section>
```

The above code is my html code and also i has added my style below

```
.tctgrid div{
     background: #ba1818;
     float: left;
     height: 120px;
     margin: 1%;
     width: 31%;
}
.tctgrid div.empty{
    background-color:#fff;
}
.psychomotor{
    width: 34%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: First of all dont have multiple `id` with the same value. use class for that

Comment: Reusing IDs (`id="question1"`) is invalid. What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean to alternate, as in show one then the other each second alternating, or do you mean show one, then the other each for a second on page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Jquery** you can wait for 2s and then hide the elements by its class name:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.square_box').hide();
}, 2000);
```

**edit**

The above will hide the both elements at the same time. If you wish to show them separately I would first update the html to add individual ID's to each element.

```
<section class="square_box tctgrid" id="question1">
</section>
<section class="square_box tctgrid" id="question2">
</section>
```

Then via Jquery.

```
$('#question2').hide(); // Hide the second question

setTimeout(function(){
   $('#question1').hide(); // Hide the first question
   $('#question2').show(); // Show the second question

   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#question2').hide(); // After 2s, hide the 2nd question
   }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Initially i need to show one section. and hide the first section and show the next section

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code. First, the script hides the second answer. Waits for 2 seconds and then hides the first question and shows the second one. Then wait again for 2 seconds more. Finally, it hides the second question.

Answer (score 0):

```
        use this code:

            <body>
              <div align="center">
                <img id="image" src="image1.png" height="200" width="200">
             </div>
             <div align="center">
                <img id="image1" src="image1.png" height="200" width="200" style="visibility:hidden;">
             </div>
            </body>
        <script>
        var hidden = false;

        setInterval(function() {
          document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = hidden ? "visible" : "hidden";
          document.getElementById("image1").style.visibility = hidden ? "hidden" : "visible";
          hidden = !hidden;
        }, 2000);

        </script>
```